# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget package performance

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am trying to use [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) nugget package. On the site it says : **ODP.NET, Managed Driver is a 100% native .NET code driver. No additional Oracle Client software is required to be installed to connect to Oracle Database.**

I wonder if they are using some wrapper around actual driver which allow it to work without installing Oracle Client but due to exact same reason it might be slow, as it might not be able to use native drivers.

native drivers are built in C and expected to be lighting fast. I am just making assumptions here.

Comment: what is the question? you can always use a decompiler, to see what the code looks like.

Comment: Usually the client code is not the bottleneck, the limitation is on the database.

Comment: Profile the SQL you are calling from the library. How does it perform?